# ASP.NET How To Refresh Data?

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, refresh

At our company, I need to keep a web page up with a list of open orders for our employees.

In the code behind, I filter the search based on what items are selected from a DropDown list `ddlList1` and a TextBox `txtSearch`, sort of like this:

```
string sql
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ddlList1.SelectedValue) &&
    !String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtSearch.Text)) {
  sql = string.Format("{0}={1}", ddlList1.SelectedValue, txtSearch.Text);
} else {
  sql = null;
}
GridView1.DataSource = db.Select(sql);
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Management wants this data to be up to date, and never over 10 minutes old.

I am not sure how to do this. Most of my code is done on Windows Forms.

So far, I have found a way to refresh the page using the `META` tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="600;Summary.aspx" />
```

However, it almost appears as though WC3 recommends against using the `refresh` property:

> Note: The value "refresh" should be used carefully, as it takes the control of a page away from the user. Using "refresh" will cause a failure in W3C's Web Content Accessibility Guidelines.

Ref: [HTML meta http-equiv](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_meta_http_equiv.asp)

So, what is the recommended way to refresh my data?

If it helps, our Server is an older SQL 2000 machine.

[Note: I found [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9177955) where someone suggested using an AJAX [UpdatePanel](http://ajax.net-tutorials.com/controls/updatepanel-control/). My Project, at this time, has no AJAX controls in it. Could I avoid the complexity of AJAX (downloading the latest package, install it into VS2010, add it to my Project's list of references, then reference AJAX in every page that uses it) or just bite the bullet?]

Comment: Just bite the bullet and drop an UpdatePanel with a Timer set to refresh the panel every 10 minutes

Comment: I am pretty sure I have installed AJAX on this machine before. How do I go about adding a reference to the Project? What is it called? I was not able to find anything under the .NET references called `AJAX`.

Comment: Add the UpdatePanel to your toolbox. It's in System.Web.Extensions.dll under C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't really do much of anything else on this page, you might as well just leave the auto refresh on.  Yes, it's annoying and I hate it and I think it shouldn't exist, but I won't have to use the site and if that's really what the clients want, that's what the client gets.

You can also use javascript or asp controls to force a refresh other than just through the HTTP meta tag, but it comes with exactly the same problems.

If you go the route of using update panels you have a few advantages.  First, and possibly most importantly, if you have much content on the page other than just the gridview being updated you aren't rendering it repeatedly.  This could (potentially) be a significant reduction in server load based on what your whole page looks like, or it could be minimal.  Next, you have a more subtle (and also customize-able) visual impact of the update for the user.  If they want the site to just flicker and be up to date, an update panel will do that without a cursor change, spinners all over, etc.  (You can also add stuff like that back in if you want it to be apparent to the users when the update panel is posting back.)

Comment: Just curious OP, what solution did you end up using?

Answer (score 1):

you can use ajax to get the data from server and populate the html container by javascript at client. i don't mean updated panels of microsoft, but xmlhttp.

Comment: Maybe, but I have no clue how to do any of the things you just described. Like I said, I usually work on Windows Forms, not web pages.

Comment: This would likely be much more work than just using update panels, especially because this is a significant amount of data with complex formatting/display requirements.  Can it be done, yes, but it's a less preferable option for these circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a simple workaround, try this :

```
<script>
   //Refreshing the page every 5 minutes
   setInterval("location.reload()", 300000);
</script>
```

Comment: Isn't this the same as `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="300;Summary.aspx" />` (what I am doing now)?

Comment: No it isn't , while with the meta you are using an html attribute (so DOM) to refresh the page, with the script you delegate the refresh to a javascript event. The same approach is used in several websites (news websites for instances).

Comment: @GiorgioMinardi It's not exactly the same, but it still accomplishes almost exactly the same thing, it has exactly the same pitfals and poor user feel, etc.  If the HTTP meta is considered inappropriate due to it's poor practice, this is no more or less acceptable of a solution.  About the only effective difference is that the meta tag will work with JavaScript disabled; this won't.